# .NET App.config. How to replace file attribute?

Tags: .net, app-config, slowcheetah

Here is short summary of current situation:
In my solution (console application) I use app.config file with entry like this:

< appSettings file="Additional.config">
On our production environment this file is provided by separate routine and we don't want to put it in projects file repository. Still we need a convenient way to run the solution in dev environment.

We've come with an idea to replace the **file** attribute using [SlowCheetach](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/). It works just fine with replacing key-value entries but we are unable to make it run correctly.

Is there a way to replace **file** property with [SlowCheetach](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/) or any other lightweight tool? We really want to avoid using build scripts to modify app.config output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution below is not working properly because id is not a valid schema element. Real solution at the bottom.

I've figured out a simple way to accomplish this. All that is needed to do is add another attribute to appSettings and set it as Match Selector so entry in app.config would look like:

```
 <appSettings file="Additional.config" id="appconfig">
```

and the one in App.Debug.config:

```
<appSettings id="appconfig" file="New/Path/To/Additional.config" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(id)">
```

## Real solution here:

It turns out that you can simply use transform in form:

```
   <appSettings xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(file)">
```

which will remove only attributes passed to RemoveAttributes and leave rest of the config intact.

More about possible transform attributes can be read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx)